# MC60 HTTP GET REQUEST ISSUE

Tags: http, server, gsm, quectel

I am using MC60ca module ,
I want to use web sockets so for handshaking from my server I have to send a HTTP GET REQUEST. The request is in the form of :

> “GET HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: echo.websocket.org:80\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\nSec-WebSocket-Key: Gsr/P3vIWH+j2U5Rmt0Bkw==\r\n\0”

I tried sending it using `HTTP EXAMPLE` of sdk1.6 but I am getting cme error 3810 and 3811
I have also done `requestheader = 1 AT+QHTTPCFG=“requestheader”,1\0`

How do I solve this request error?

The code is attached below

```
#ifdef EXAMPLE_HTTP
#include “custom_feature_def.h”
#include “ql_type.h”
#include “ql_stdlib.h”
#include “ql_trace.h”
#include “ql_timer.h”
#include “ql_uart.h”
#include “ql_error.h”
#include “ql_gprs.h”
#include “ql_fs.h”
#include “ril.h”
#include “ril_network.h”
#include “ril_http.h”

#define DEBUG_ENABLE 1
#if DEBUG_ENABLE > 0
#define DEBUG_PORT UART_PORT1
#define DBG_BUF_LEN 512
static char DBG_BUFFER[DBG_BUF_LEN];
#define APP_DEBUG(FORMAT,…) {
Ql_memset(DBG_BUFFER, 0, DBG_BUF_LEN);
Ql_sprintf(DBG_BUFFER,FORMAT,##VA_ARGS);
if (UART_PORT2 == (DEBUG_PORT))
{
Ql_Debug_Trace(DBG_BUFFER);
} else {
Ql_UART_Write((Enum_SerialPort)(DEBUG_PORT), (u8*)(DBG_BUFFER), Ql_strlen((const char *)(DBG_BUFFER)));
}
}
#else
#define APP_DEBUG(FORMAT,…)
#endif

/****************************************************************************

Define http parameters
****************************************************************************/
#define APN_NAME “CMNET\0”
#define APN_USERID “”
#define APN_PASSWD “”
#define HTTP_REQUEST 0 // 0=http-get, 1=http-post, 2=http-file

//
// http url address
//
#if (HTTP_REQUEST == 0)
// url for http-get
#define HTTP_URL_ADDR “GET HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: echo.websocket.org:80\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\nSec-WebSocket-Key: Gsr/P3vIWH+j2U5Rmt0Bkw==\r\n\0”
//#define HTTP_URL_ADDR “GET /2016/04/create-xml-request-in-c-for-server.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.aticleworld.com\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n\0”
//#define HTTP_URL_ADDR "GET /demo/AC001/AC001(6).txt HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: techxinnovations.in\r\nConnection: Keep-alive\r\nAccept: /\r\n\r\n "
#elif (HTTP_REQUEST == 1)
// url for http-post
//#define HTTP_URL_ADDR “https://www.google.com\0”
#define HTTP_URL_ADDR “http://echo.websocket.org\0”
//#define HTTP_URL_ADDR “http://www.quectel.com/\0”
#elif (HTTP_REQUEST == 2)
// url for http-file
#define HTTP_URL_ADDR “http://124.74.41.170:5015/index.html\0”
#endif

// for http-post (HTTP_REQUEST=1)
//#define HTTP_POST_MSG “GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n\0”
#define HTTP_POST_MSG “GET HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: echo.websocket.org:80\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\nSec-WebSocket-Key: Gsr/P3vIWH+j2U5Rmt0Bkw==\r\n\0”
// for downloading file via http (HTTP_REQUEST=2)
#define RAM_FILE_NAME “RAM:http.file\0”
#define RAM_FILE_SIZE 4096

u8 arrHttpRcvBuf[101024]; // 10K buffer for http data
static void HTTP_Program(u8 get_post);
static void Callback_HTTP_DwnldFile(u32 dllSize, u32 cntntLen, s32 errCode);
static void Callback_UART_Hdlr(Enum_SerialPort port, Enum_UARTEventType msg, bool level, void customizedPara);
static void SIM_Card_State_Ind(u32 sim_stat);

void proc_main_task(s32 taskId)
{
ST_MSG msg;

// Register & open UART port
Ql_UART_Register(UART_PORT1, Callback_UART_Hdlr, NULL);
Ql_UART_Open(UART_PORT1, 115200, FC_NONE);

Ql_UART_Register(UART_PORT2, Callback_UART_Hdlr, NULL);
Ql_UART_Open(UART_PORT2, 115200, FC_NONE);

APP_DEBUG("\r\nOpenCPU: example for HTTP programming\r\n");
while (1)
{
    Ql_OS_GetMessage(&msg);
    switch(msg.message)
    {
        case MSG_ID_RIL_READY:
            APP_DEBUG("<-- RIL is ready -->\r\n");
            Ql_RIL_Initialize();
        case MSG_ID_URC_INDICATION:
            switch (msg.param1)
            {
            case URC_SYS_INIT_STATE_IND:
                APP_DEBUG("<-- Sys Init Status %d -->\r\n", msg.param2);
                break;
            case URC_CFUN_STATE_IND:
                APP_DEBUG("<-- CFUN Status:%d -->\r\n", msg.param2);
                break;
            case URC_SIM_CARD_STATE_IND:
                SIM_Card_State_Ind(msg.param2);
                break;
            case URC_GSM_NW_STATE_IND:
                APP_DEBUG("<-- GSM Network Status:%d -->\r\n", msg.param2);
                break;
            case URC_GPRS_NW_STATE_IND:
                APP_DEBUG("<-- GPRS Network Status:%d -->\r\n", msg.param2);
                if (NW_STAT_REGISTERED == msg.param2 || NW_STAT_REGISTERED_ROAMING == msg.param2)
                {
                    // GPRS is ready.
                    // Now, you can start to program http
                    if (0 == HTTP_REQUEST)
                    {// HTTP-get
                        HTTP_Program(0);
                    }
                    else if (1 == HTTP_REQUEST)
                    {// HTTP-post
                        HTTP_Program(1);
                    }
                    else if (2 == HTTP_REQUEST)
                    {// HTTP downlaod file
                        HTTP_Program(2);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
}

static void SIM_Card_State_Ind(u32 sim_stat)
{
switch (sim_stat)
{
case SIM_STAT_NOT_INSERTED:
APP_DEBUG("<-- SIM Card Status: NOT INSERTED -->\r\n");
break;
case SIM_STAT_READY:
APP_DEBUG("<-- SIM Card Status: READY -->\r\n");
break;
case SIM_STAT_PIN_REQ:
APP_DEBUG("<-- SIM Card Status: SIM PIN -->\r\n");
break;
case SIM_STAT_PUK_REQ:
APP_DEBUG("<-- SIM Card Status: SIM PUK -->\r\n");
break;
case SIM_STAT_PH_PIN_REQ:
APP_DEBUG("<-- SIM Card Status: PH-SIM PIN -->\r\n");
break;
case SIM_STAT_PH_PUK_REQ:
APP_DEBUG("<-- SIM Card Status: PH-SIM PUK -->\r\n");
break;
case SIM_STAT_PIN2_REQ:
APP_DEBUG("<-- SIM Card Status: SIM PIN2 -->\r\n");
break;
case SIM_STAT_PUK2_REQ:
APP_DEBUG("<-- SIM Card Status: SIM PUK2 -->\r\n");
break;
case SIM_STAT_BUSY:
APP_DEBUG("<-- SIM Card Status: BUSY -->\r\n");
break;
case SIM_STAT_NOT_READY:
APP_DEBUG("<-- SIM Card Status: NOT READY -->\r\n");
break;
default:
APP_DEBUG("<-- SIM Card Status: ERROR -->\r\n");
break;
}
}
s32 RIL_HTTP_SETCONTENT(u16 len)
{
    s32  retRes;
    s32  errCode = RIL_AT_FAILED;
    char strAT[30];


    Ql_sprintf(strAT, "AT+QHTTPCFG=\"contextid\",%d\0", len);
    retRes = Ql_RIL_SendATCmd(strAT, Ql_strlen(strAT), ATRsp_QHTTP_Handler, &errCode, 0);
    if (retRes != RIL_AT_SUCCESS)
    {
        if (RIL_AT_FAILED == errCode)
        {
            return retRes;
        } else {
            return errCode;
        }
    }



    Ql_sprintf(strAT, "AT+QHTTPCFG=\"requestheader\",%d\0", len);
        retRes = Ql_RIL_SendATCmd(strAT, Ql_strlen(strAT), ATRsp_QHTTP_Handler, &errCode, 0);
        if (retRes != RIL_AT_SUCCESS)
        {
            if (RIL_AT_FAILED == errCode)
            {
                return retRes;
            } else {
                return errCode;
            }
        }


    Ql_sprintf(strAT, "AT+QHTTPCFG=\"responseheader\",%d\0", len);
            retRes = Ql_RIL_SendATCmd(strAT, Ql_strlen(strAT), ATRsp_QHTTP_Handler, &errCode, 0);
            if (retRes != RIL_AT_SUCCESS)
            {
                if (RIL_AT_FAILED == errCode)
                {
                    return retRes;
                } else {
                    return errCode;
                }
            }

    return retRes;
}
static u32 m_rcvDataLen = 0;
static void HTTP_RcvData(u8* ptrData, u32 dataLen, void* reserved)
{
APP_DEBUG("<-- Data coming on http, total len:%d -->\r\n", m_rcvDataLen + dataLen);
if ((m_rcvDataLen + dataLen) <= sizeof(arrHttpRcvBuf))
{
Ql_memcpy((void*)(arrHttpRcvBuf + m_rcvDataLen), (const void*)ptrData, dataLen);
} else {
if (m_rcvDataLen < sizeof(arrHttpRcvBuf))
{// buffer is not enough
u32 realAcceptLen = sizeof(arrHttpRcvBuf) - m_rcvDataLen;
Ql_memcpy((void*)(arrHttpRcvBuf + m_rcvDataLen), (const void*)ptrData, realAcceptLen);
APP_DEBUG("<-- Rcv-buffer is not enough, discard part of data (len:%d/%d) -->\r\n", dataLen - realAcceptLen, dataLen);
} else {// No more buffer
APP_DEBUG("<-- No more buffer, discard data (len:%d) -->\r\n", dataLen);
}
}
m_rcvDataLen += dataLen;
}

static void HTTP_Program(u8 http_action)
{
s32 ret;
//u32 readDataLen = 0;

// Set PDP context
ret = RIL_NW_SetGPRSContext(Ql_GPRS_GetPDPContextId());
APP_DEBUG("<-- Set GPRS PDP context, ret=%d -->\r\n", ret);

// Set APN
ret = RIL_NW_SetAPN(1, APN_NAME, APN_USERID, APN_PASSWD);
APP_DEBUG("<-- Set GPRS APN, ret=%d -->\r\n", ret);

// Open/Activate PDP context
ret = RIL_NW_OpenPDPContext();
APP_DEBUG("<-- Open PDP context, ret=%d -->\r\n", ret);
ret=RIL_HTTP_SETCONTENT(1);                                                 //AT+QHTTPCFG=\"requestheader\",1\0
APP_DEBUG("<-- RIL_HTTP_SETCONTENT, ret=%d -->\r\n", ret);
// Set HTTP server address (URL)
ret = RIL_HTTP_SetServerURL(HTTP_URL_ADDR, Ql_strlen(HTTP_URL_ADDR));
APP_DEBUG("<-- Set http server URL, ret=%d -->\r\n", ret);

// Send get/post request
m_rcvDataLen = 0;
if (0 == http_action)
{
    // get-request
    APP_DEBUG("BEFORE GET REQUET\r\n");
    ret = RIL_HTTP_RequestToGet(100);   // 100s timetout
    APP_DEBUG("<-- Send get-request, ret=%d -->\r\n", ret);

    // Read response from server
    ret = RIL_HTTP_ReadResponse(120, HTTP_RcvData);
    APP_DEBUG("<-- Read http response data, ret=%d, dataLen=%d -->\r\n", ret, m_rcvDataLen);
}
else if (1 == http_action)
{
    // post-request
    APP_DEBUG("BEFORE GET IN POST REQUET\r\n");
    ret = RIL_HTTP_RequestToPost(HTTP_POST_MSG, Ql_strlen((char*)HTTP_POST_MSG));
    APP_DEBUG("<-- Send post-request, postMsg=%s, ret=%d -->\r\n", (char*)HTTP_POST_MSG, ret);

    // Read response from server
    ret = RIL_HTTP_ReadResponse(120, HTTP_RcvData);
    APP_DEBUG("<-- Read http response data, ret=%d, dataLen=%d -->\r\n", ret, m_rcvDataLen);
}
else if (2 == http_action){
    // get-request
    ret = RIL_HTTP_RequestToGet(100);   // 100s timetout
    APP_DEBUG("<-- Send get-request, ret=%d -->\r\n", ret);

    // Download file from http server
    ret = RIL_HTTP_DownloadFile(RAM_FILE_NAME, RAM_FILE_SIZE, Callback_HTTP_DwnldFile);
    APP_DEBUG("<-- Download file from http server, ret=%d -->\r\n", ret);
}

// Close PDP context
ret = RIL_NW_ClosePDPContext();
APP_DEBUG("<-- Close PDP context, ret=%d -->\r\n", ret);
}

static void Callback_HTTP_DwnldFile(u32 dllSize, u32 cntntLen, s32 errCode)
{
s32 iRet;
APP_DEBUG("<-- Finished to download file from http server, dllSize=%d, cntntLen=%d, errCode=%d -->\r\n", dllSize, cntntLen, errCode);
iRet = Ql_FS_GetSize((char*)RAM_FILE_NAME);
APP_DEBUG("<-- Check RAM file:%s, size:%d -->\r\n", (char*)RAM_FILE_NAME, iRet);
}

static void Callback_UART_Hdlr(Enum_SerialPort port, Enum_UARTEventType msg, bool level, void* customizedPara)
{
APP_DEBUG(“Callback_UART_Hdlr: port=%d, event=%d, level=%d, p=%x\r\n”, port, msg, level, customizedPara);
}

#endif //EXAMPLE_FTP
```